# SQLite not updating multiple rows using LIKE

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to update rows using multiple `LIKE` clauses with the following command:

```
    UPDATE Item SET CategoryID = '6' WHERE
    Title LIKE '%ASP%' AND 
    Title LIKE '%C#%' AND 
    Title LIKE '%VB%' AND 
    Title LIKE '%iPhone%' AND 
    Title LIKE '%CSS%' AND 
    Title LIKE '%HTML%' AND 
    Title LIKE '%PHP%' AND 
    Title LIKE '%Oracle%';
```

When the command is executed, SQLite tells me that the query executed successfully, but when checking the table no rows have been updated.

When I tried the same command with only one `like` clause

```
    UPDATE Item SET CategoryID = '6' WHERE
    Title LIKE '%ASP%';
```

the relevant rows updated perfectly. So I am stuck on how to update the rows using multiple LIKE clauses. 
Please Help.

Comment: Perhaps you should use OR instead of AND...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE Item SET CategoryID = '6' WHERE
Title LIKE '%ASP%' OR
Title LIKE '%C#%' OR 
Title LIKE '%VB%' OR 
Title LIKE '%iPhone%' OR 
Title LIKE '%CSS%' OR 
Title LIKE '%HTML%' OR 
Title LIKE '%PHP%' OR 
Title LIKE '%Oracle%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is looking for the row to contain ***all*** of those `%ASP%`, `%C#%`... etc.  I'm assuming based on your second query you want to do the update based on ***any*** of those terms.  That's `or`, not `and`

```
UPDATE Item 
SET CategoryID = '6' 
WHERE
    Title LIKE '%ASP%' 
    OR Title LIKE '%C#%' 
    OR Title LIKE '%VB%' 
    OR Title LIKE '%iPhone%' 
    OR Title LIKE '%CSS%' 
    OR Title LIKE '%HTML%' 
    OR Title LIKE '%PHP%' 
    OR Title LIKE '%Oracle%';
```

Sample:

1. the brown asp jumped over the c#.
2. The brown asp jumped

Query 1:

```
UPDATE Item 
SET CategoryID = '6' 
WHERE
    Title LIKE '%ASP%' 
    AND Title LIKE '%C#%'
```

Query 2:

```
UPDATE Item 
SET CategoryID = '6' 
WHERE
    Title LIKE '%ASP%' 
    OR Title LIKE '%C#%'
```

`1` would be matched by `query 1` and `query 2`, as 1 contains both ASP and C#.  `Query 1` checks for ***both*** of those, `query 2` checks for ***any***.

`2` would only be matched by `query 2`, because `2` does not contain both "asp" and "c#". It only contains "asp", which satisfies the question "does sample 2 contain the characters "asp" or "c#" - and the answer is yes, because it contains "asp".  If you applied that same question to `2` using `query 1` - "Does sample 2 contain the characters "asp" and "c#" the answer is no/false, because it only contains one of the two.